# "how to call the post api with login credential like username and password with easiest way using flutter"

Tags: flutter

how to call the post api with login credential like username and password with easiest way using flutter please let me know the how manys to call post api in Flutter.

Comment: please implement in some simple way assume that we are putting the username and password in textbox and after clicking on the login button it gets call.. i am beginner in flutter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some code.

Answer (score 0):

By using below method you can send your data in header or body.

```
new http.Client()
.post(url, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json','username':'****','password':'****'},
  body: JSON.encoder.convert({'username':'****','password':'****'}))
  .then((http.Response r) => r.body)
  .whenComplete(() => print('completed'));
```

Comment: Thanks @sreeramu for your answer and giving me good explanation...can you please let me know that how to fetch the details from the api suppose my api structure is like { profile{'','','',......},'role{'', '' ,....},'mu'{' ', ' ',......}}